# How to implement publish/subscribe communication over cross machine

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

I have a .Net service hosted on a server windows 2008, and .Net clients connecting to this server over the internet.

I want to implement a publish subscribe model same Microsoft sample using wsDualHttpBinding  where clients can subscribe to events on the service and have data pushed to them as data becomes available.

I have implemented service on server and able to browse successfully. But when i try to communicate from client it will end up with timeout(I have increased the time property on config file on both file client and server)

Client config file:

```
<client>
  <endpoint name="" address="http://x.x.x.x/servicemodelsamples/service.svc" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ISampleContract"/>
</client>

<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <!--If running in cross machine then replace localhost with the FQDN of the machine on whihc datasource.exe is run-->
    <binding name="Binding1" clientBaseAddress="http://xxxx:xxxx/myClient/" closeTimeout="00:05:00"
        openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
      </security>

    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WSDualHttpBinding` doesn't work for normal clients over the internet.

This answer explains why: [Connecting over internet to WCF service using wsDualHttpBinding times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526284/connecting-over-internet-to-wcf-service-using-wsdualhttpbinding-times-out)

Since your clients are .NET, you should be able to use a duplex `NetTcpBinding`

Comment: Hi Nicholas, will NetTcpBinding work ok, without having to open ports on the clients (this is what we are trying to avoid having to do)?

Comment: @DermFrench yes - if you establish a TCP connection from a client to a server, then then the server can use the same connection to initiate sending data to the client as long as the connection is open.

Comment: Nicholas that sounds like what Sonal wants (she is a colleague of mine).  So basically with TCP setup, we only need to open a port on the server, and then we can still do pub/sub?

Comment: @DermFrench yes - that will work. Also, as it's .NET to .NET, you can use a binary encoding, which is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nichols, we have implemented using nettcpbinding and working as expected.